# How to listen from radio device?

Tags: mplayer

I have a radio card with /dev/radio correctly created. I've connected my radio card to soundcard, on line-in port, I run mplayer and I listen...silence.

```
mplayer -radio adevice=hw=0.0:arate=96000 -rawaudio rate=96000 radio://103.8
```

Modules are loaded

```
lsmod |grep -i alsa
saa7134_alsa           11554  0
saa7134               163772  1 saa7134_alsa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very old, and I don't know which radio card you have(had), but it sounds like you connected to what looks like an external 1/8 plug on the radio card, possibly black in color. That is actually the antenna port. It uses a mono plug and wants 2 unshield wires one on tip and one on ring about 3 feet long. A cheap (poor shielding) pair of headphones can work if the antenna cable is missing.

An internal connection is made to the sound card using a cd audio style cable for the audio in this case. These usually have one I/O address line for controlling the radio, but it is looks like the software you are using abstracts that information for you.